# Trying to put lua scripts into folders. Love2D

Tags: lua, directory, love2d

Ok, so i've made a game using love2D and I tried converting it into a .app, because i'm running Mac OSX. But I got the error saying that main.lua needs to be that the top level of the .zip. So I tried putting all of my lua scripts into a folder leaving only the main.lua and the conf.lua in the top level of the .zip. But now love2D cannot find the other files in the folder. I tried putting the name of the directory when using "require." for instance:

```
    require "dir/player.lua"
```

but that wouldn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
require "dir.player"
```

The dot `.` denotes a parent level, the `.lua` is not needed.

Comment: This works for `require`. Is there a way to provide a platform independent directory to other functions? Say I have a `.wav` file I want to load through `love.audio.newSource` and it is in `sound` folder. In Windows the obvious way to go is `sound = love.audio.newSource('sound/file.wav')`. How to make `dir` cross-platform?

Comment: Well, i'm not sure about this, but i'm on linux and i would use the exact same syntax. What exactly is platform dependent in this line? I would say it depends on the handling of paths of love, especially in this case its audio loading routine.